# Verilog code for three-storey building

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, state-machines, frequency-divider

Ground, first and second floors and the inputs are r0 for ground, r1 for first floor, and r2 for second floor. The output will be d1, d2, up1, up2, and n (no action). Frequency is 2<sup>15</sup> Hz.

State diagram (Moore design) for a lift (elevator):

[image: ground floor]

[image: First floor]

[image: second floor]

This is the code I tried:

```
module lift(input clk_in,rst,input [1:0]r,output reg [2:0]out, output reg clk_out);
  parameter g0 = 4'b0000; //ground floor with no action
  parameter g1 = 4'b0001; //ground floor with d1 output
  parameter g2 = 4'b0010; //ground floor with d2 output
  parameter f0 = 4'b0011; //first floor
  parameter f1 = 4'b0100; //first floor with up1
  parameter f2 = 4'b0101; //first floor with d1
  parameter s0 = 4'b0110; //second floor
  parameter s1 = 4'b0111; //second floor with up1
  parameter s2 = 4'b1000; //second floor with up2
  
  //outputs
  parameter n = 3'b000; 
  parameter d1 = 3'b001; 
  parameter d2 = 3'b010; 
  parameter up1 = 3'b011;
  parameter up2 = 3'b100;
  
  //inputs
  parameter r0 = 2'b00; 
  parameter r1 = 2'b01; 
  parameter r2 = 2'b10; 
  
  //current and next state registers 
  reg [3:0] state, nxt_state;
  
//clockDivider
reg[15:0]counter=16'd0;
parameter DIVISOR = 16'd32768;
always @(posedge clk_in)
begin
counter<=counter+16'd1;
if(counter>=(DIVISOR-1))
begin
counter<=16'd0;
end
clk_out<=(counter<DIVISOR/2)?1'b1:1'b0;
end
  
always@(posedge clk_out,posedge rst) begin
    if(rst == 1)
      state <= g0;
    else
      state <= nxt_state;
  end
  always@(state ,r) begin
    case(state)
      g0 : begin 
        if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g0;
        else if(r==r1)
          nxt_state <= f1;
        else 
          nxt_state <= s2; 
      end
      g1 : begin
        if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g0;
        else if(r==r1)
          nxt_state <= f1;
        else 
          nxt_state <= s2; 
      end
      g2 : begin
        if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g0;
        else if(r==r1)
          nxt_state <= f1;
        else 
          nxt_state <= s2; 
      end
      f0 : begin
        if(r == r1)
          nxt_state <= f0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g1;
        else
          nxt_state <= s1;
      end
      f1 : begin
       if(r == r1)
          nxt_state <= f0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g1;
        else
          nxt_state <= s1;
      end
      f2 : begin
       if(r == r1)
          nxt_state <= f0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g1;
        else
          nxt_state <= s1;
      end
      s0 : begin
       if(r == r2)
          nxt_state <= s0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g2;
        else
          nxt_state <= f2;
      end 
      s1 : begin
       if(r == r2)
          nxt_state <= s0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g2;
        else
          nxt_state <= f2;
      end 
      s2 : begin
       if(r == r2)
          nxt_state <= s0;
        else if(r == r0)
          nxt_state <= g2;
        else
          nxt_state <= f2;
      end
      default : nxt_state <= g0;
    endcase
  end
  always@(state) begin
    case(state)
      g0 : out <= n;
      g1 : out <= d1;
      g2 : out <= d2;
      f0 : out <= n;
      f1 : out <= up1;
      f2 : out <= d1;
      s0 : out <= n;
      s1 : out <= up1;
      s2 : out <= up2;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module tb();
reg clk_in;
reg rst;
reg [1:0] r;
wire [2:0] out;
wire clk_out;

lift uut (clk_in, rst, r, out, clk_out);

initial begin
 clk_in = 0;
 forever #15259 clk_in = ~clk_in;
end 

initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  r = 2'b00;
  rst = 1;
  // Wait 100 us for global reset to finish
  #91554;
  rst = 0;
  #61036;
  r = 2'b00;
  #30518;
  r = 2'b01;
  #30518;
  r = 2'b10;
  #30518;
  r = 2'b00;
  #30518;
  r = 2'b10; 
  #30518;
  r = 2'b01; 
  $stop;
end
      
endmodule
```

The input is not changing according to the divided `clk_out`:

[image: simulation]

Comment: which part of a building requires a state machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently change `r` on every `clk_in` positive edge.  If you want to change `r` every time `clk_out` changes, you can wait for an event on `clk_out` (like the negative edge).  I modified the testbench `initial` block to replace most of the `#` delays to demonstrate:

```
initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  r = 2'b00;
  rst = 1;
  // Wait 100 us for global reset to finish
  #91554;
  rst = 0;
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b00;
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b01;
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b10;
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b00;
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b10; 
  @(negedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b01;
  $finish;
end
```

[image: waves]